# Ubuntu 22.04/Windows 10 dual boot grub issues

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, grub-efi

I have a problem. I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 onto a single hard drive (I have another but that is for my parents.) and it just boots me to the grub command line (NOT grub rescue) every time the computer restarts, and then I have to type in these commands:

`ls` (This is to check which partition has grub. The (hd1,gpt5) can sometimes be something else.)

```
set prefix=(hd1,gpt5)/boot/grub

set root=(hd1,gpt5)

insmod normal

normal
```

After that I am taken to the grub boot menu, which shows me that it clearly works and is present, but I'd like a way to do it without typing in the commands every time. Boot Repair just returns an error message, reinstalling grub or Ubuntu hasn't done anything, and I'm not willing to touch BIOS/UEFI without absolute certainty that my computer won't burn out or something. I'm aware of Super Grub Rescue 2, or whatever that thing was called, but that's a last resort more than anything at this point. The computer itself is an Aspire TC-780 PC with 8 GB of RAM and plenty of drive space (>800 GB?). Help is appreciated. Note that Windows Disk Management doesn't recognize the Ubuntu OS partition, which I made around 189 GB or something like that.

P.S. I'd also like to share my folders and files between the 2 OS's as well. I'd also like to be able to do that without infringing on user permissions, which is an option but a really insecure one at that. Switching to Ubuntu is lucrative, so shared files are good.

Comment: what error message does Boot Repair return?

Comment: sharing files and folders should be done with a separate, shared partition. Windows can't see your Ubuntu partition because it is formatted as ext4, and Windows can't read ext4.

Comment: I don't really remember what Boot Repair error message I got. I think it was most likely 'boot not recognized' or something along those lines. I'm honestly not sure.